# Question on Model completeness in FOL

Tags: logic, model-theory

Claim: Suppose T is model complete and has a model embeddable in every model of T. Show T is complete.

This is in Sacks' book Saturated Model theory, problem 8.4.

Is the following proof correct?

Proof: Suppose T is model complete & $\forall$M|= T & $\exists$f, N s.t. f: N|-->X $\subset$M, with f an elementary monomorphism. Thus by assumption, $\forall$ $\phi$$\in$T ($\phi$ has no free variables)N|=$\phi$ iff X|= f($\phi$). Thus M|= f($\phi$); since choice of X, $\phi$ was arbitrary, we have X|= f($\phi$) iff M|= f($\phi$), thus M is elementarily equivalent to X. So $\exists$g: M|-->X & is an e.m. By problem 7.7. T is complete iff $\exists$f, g which are e.m. between models of T having the same range, (and f,g above have the same X), so T is complete. END OF PROOF.

Or maybe I'm supposed to use Robinson diagrams?

Thanks!

Comment: Elementary equivalence is a much weaker notion than isomorphism. Structures $A$ and $B$ can be elementarily equivalent even though there are no homomorphisms from $A$ to $B$ or from $B$ to $A$. So $g$ in your proof may not exist. Instead, try to prove that for every sentence $\phi$, $T \vdash \phi$ iff $N \models \phi$ and then argue that either $N \models \phi$ or $N \not\models \phi$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Rob! I'll give it a shot in a little bit and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, I figured this out a *long* time ago! but better late than never.

Comment: Ok, I figured this out a *long* time ago! but better late than never. So suppose T is model complete and has a model embed able in every model of T. Trying the strategy suggested by Rob Arthan above,we have to show T|- $\phi$ iff N |= $\phi$; then we show either N |= $\phi$ or N does not |= $\phi$. So suppose T|- $\phi$. By hypothesis, There is an X |= T; hence X |= $\phi$. Thus there is a submodel Y |= $\phi$. By hypothesis there is an embedding f: Z --> X. Hence since choice of Y is arbitary, we have that Y = f(Z) and so $\phi$ = f($\psy$) for $\psy$ $\in$ Z. Hence Y |= $\phi$.